# Visual studio intellisense has problems with typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using typescript in asp.net project. I transpile it with npx tsc, and everything works fine.
The only problem is that intellisense in visual studio with resharper shows errors in typescript file in places which are fine. Right now I use visual studio code for editing typescript as workaround, but I would like to use just visul studio.

Example of error

```
new Promise((resolve)=>{
   ///some code here
   resolve(null);
});
```

Error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: parameter type mismatch. Parameter 'value' should have type assignable to (Object | PromiseLike | undefined) but is has type 'null'

Comment: What is the error showing on? Can you give some more code?